# Running Robot Framework UI tests in Bamboo

Tags: robotframework, bamboo, bitbucket-server, selenium2library

I would just like to ask if it's possible to run UI tests in Bamboo Integration?
I mean, can Bamboo open a browser instance(headful)?

I am using Robot Framework with Selenium2Library. Uploaded it to Stash repository.
So I was wondering if it's possible for Bamboo to point to Stash and run the UI test cases.

Comment: I did some UI tests with Robot and Bamboo a few projects ago. I think I used virtual framebuffer to run browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course!
I used it successfully .Use remoteWebdriver to launch selenium standalone jar/webDriver.
It works.